# How to select any number of digits with regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will extract the numbers after `directory/` in the following URL:

```
http://www.website.com/directory/9892639512/alphanum3r1c/some-more-text-here/0892735235
```

If I know the number of digits, then this regex I wrote works:

```
directory\/([0-9]{7})\/
```

However, if I remove the number of digits to match `{7}`, then the regex stops working.

Live demo: http://regex101.com/r/wX3eI2

I've been trying different, things, but can't seem to get the regex to work without explicitly setting the number of characters to match.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change regex to:

```
directory\/([0-9]+)\/
```

The `{7}` means, 7 characters (in this case only numbers). The `+` means one or more characters (in this case numbers).